# How can I convince typescript that it's ok to call Observable operators on a Subject?

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, rxjs5

Example code, using Angular 4.1.3, rxjs 5.3.0, typescript 2.2.2:

```
import { Subject } from 'rxjs'

export class Example {
  public response$: Subject<boolean>;

  public confirm(prompt: string): Subject<boolean> {
    // ...set up a confirmation dialog...
    this.response$ = new Subject<boolean>();
    return this.response$.first();
  }
}
```

When I try to compile this code, typescript complains about the last line:

```
The 'this' context of type 'Subject<boolean>' is not assignable to method's 'this' of type 'Observable<boolean>'.
  Types of property 'lift' are incompatible.
    Type '<R>(operator: Operator<boolean, R>) => Observable<boolean>' is not assignable to type '<R>(operator: Operator<boolean, R>) => Observable<R>'.
  Type 'Observable<boolean>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<R>'.
    Type 'boolean' is not assignable to type 'R'.
```

My sense is that this is saying that `first()` is a method of Observable, not Subject, but my understanding is that a Subject is also an Observable, so this should not be a problem. And, in fact, if I ignore the error the code compiles and runs fine.

Things I have tried:

1. Various ways of importing the `first` operator explicitly, e.g. `import 'rxjs/add/operator/first'`. This does not change the error.
2. Casting the Subject to an Observable before calling `first()`, e.g. `return (this.response$ as Observable<boolean>).first();`. This results in a different but similar error, which also seems incorrect to me: `Type 'Observable<boolean>' is not assignable to type 'Subject<boolean>'. Property 'observers' is missing in type 'Observable<boolean>'.`

How can I convince typescript that it is valid to call `first()` on a Subject?

To clarify in response to the discussion of return types below: the method may also have had an incorrect return type (should be Observable rather than Subject) but that appears to be a separate issue; changing the return type does not resolve the error described above. A further detail confirming this is that when vscode highlights the error, it only highlights `this.response$`, not the entire return line, suggesting that the problem is between `this.response$` and `first()`, not between `first()` and the function's signature:

[image: error highlighted in vscode]

Comment: .first() gives you an `Observable`, not a `Subject`. Change your methods return type to `Observable<boolean>`

Comment: I think @ggradnig is right. Maybe you can even remove the explicit return type declaration. Typescript inference should be able to recognize that `confirm` returns an Observable<boolean>

Comment: Actually, it *will* return a subject, as  `Subject` implements `lift`. However, this cannot be expressed via TypeScript. For more information, see [this comment](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/issues/3574#issuecomment-382357300).

Comment: @cartant - there is something I would like to understand better/  `this.response$.first()` returns an `Observable` even if `this.response$` is a Subject. `confirm(prompt: string): Subject<boolean>` states that the method should return a `Subject`. Isn't this the problem? I mean the fact that an `Observable` can not be returned by a method that states to return a `Subject`?

Comment: @Picci It's **typed** as returning an observable, but sources are able to implement `lift` to determine what is actually returned when an operator is applied. And `Subject` implements `lift` to ensure that after operators are applied, a `Subject`-based instance is still returned. The link in the comment I made above will take you to a comment I made in the repo and that comment includes links to the relevant source. That's how it works in v5 and v6, but `lift` is going to be removed in v7, IIRC.

Comment: @cartant Thanks. It is clear. What is returned is a **Subject** but TypeScript can not get it and therefore the error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TL;DR:** Stricter type checks introduced in TypeScript 2.4 are not compatible with RxJS < 5.4.2 ([due to a bug](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/pull/2722)). Your IDE is probably using TypeScript >= 2.4 for type checks. Either upgrade RxJS (recommended), downgrade TypeScript, or use the programatic solution `Subject.asObservable` together with a return type `Observable<boolean>`.

**Explanation:**

After the discussion, I looked into the RxJS 5.3.0 source code and found that the signatures of `lift` differ between `Subject` and `Observable`. Specifically, we can see the following difference:

[Subject.ts:](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/5.3.0/src/Subject.ts)

```
lift<R>(operator: Operator<T, R>): Observable<T>
```

[Observable.ts:](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/5.3.0/src/Observable.ts)

```
lift<R>(operator: Operator<T, R>): Observable<R>
```

The Generic Type of the returned Observable is **T** in `Subject`, but **R** in `Observable`.

The `first()` operator requires an `Observable` for its `this` context, that can't be matched by `Subject` due to the mismatching signatures of `lift`. This is very strange to me, as `Subject` extends `Observable` and therefore should have matching signatures for all its properties.

Now here is the solution: TypeScript introduced stricter type checks with version 2.4 and indeed RxJS needed to catch up with that change by changing the signature of the `lift` method. This change can be seen [in the changelog](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md) at version **5.4.2**.:

> Subject: lift signature is now appropriate for stricter TypeScript 2.4 checks

[Here is the corresponding issue](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/pull/2722). It seems to have been a bug.

You're running RxJS **5.3**, so that's why you get the error.

There are two options. Either upgrade RxJS (recommended) or use `Subject.asObservable` to change the type from `Subject` to `Observable`.

As mentioned in my comment, the return type of your function needs to change to `Observable<boolean>` as well.

Applied on your snipped, this should look like this:

```
public confirm(prompt: string): Observable<boolean> {
    // ...set up a confirmation dialog...
    this.response$ = new Subject<boolean>();
    return this.response$.asObservable().first();
  }
```

I see your TypeScript version is **2.2**, but it may very well be that your IDE uses another TypeScript version for type checks.

**Alternative**

As mentioned by @cartant, `Subject.lift` is implemented to return a `Subject`, but that can't be expressed with TypeScript's types (no return type overloading, not even sure if there is a language that supports that).

So, another solution is to ignore the type checks by casting to `<any>`. That way you can also return `Subject`.

Comment: Very thorough, and correct! Updating to RxJS 5.5.12 and changing the function's return type to `Observable<boolean>` cleared the error.

Answer (score 3):

Your understanding that a Subject is also an Observable is correct but to an extent that a **Subject can also be used as an Observable**. But that doesn't make a `Subject` an `Observable` and vice versa.

As suggested by ggradnig you should be changing the return type of your `confirm` function to `Observable<boolean>` instead of `Subject<boolean>` since the `first` method on the `Subject<boolean>` would return an `Observable<boolean>`

```
import { Subject } from 'rxjs'

export class Example {
  public response$: Subject < boolean > ;

  public confirm(prompt: string): Observable<boolean> {
    // ...set up a confirmation dialog...
    this.response$ = new Subject < boolean > ();
    return this.response$.first();
  }
}
```

Comment: This makes sense, but unfortunately it does not resolve the error. I have tried both changing the return type of `confirm()` to `Observable<boolean>` and also omitting the return type and letting typescript infer it, but the original error remains unchanged. I believe this is because typescript is objecting to a (perceived) mismatch related to `first` being called on `response$`, not the mismatch of the output of `first()` with the function signature.